# Display bidirectional and composition relation UML class diagram

Tags: class, uml, composition, bidirectional, relation

I have two classes Event and Review.

The event has an instance object Review in it. 
A review also has an object Event in it.
This means a bidirectional relationship between them (two arrows).

When an event is deleted the review will also be deleted.
This means a composition relationship between them (filled diamond at Event).

Now my question is: 
How can I display the two arrows and the filled diamond together in the same line?

I'm wondering if I should left out the directional relation when showing the composition or aggregation?
With association the direction arrow(s) can be displayed with no problem, but having the diamond there is a problem...

Comment: Are you sure this design is appropriate? Is the relation between Review And Event really a bidirectional composition? Also - which uml tool are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the headline of the question: bidirectional navigations can be shown using a double arrow (one at each end) or no arrow at all (since the association is bidirectional, there´s no need to add arrows).

Comment: Okay thanks, I am new to UML and I have read in a book that a double arrow is displayed for bidirectional, so now I know no arrows can also be used for. :)